# How can I use overlapping pairs of data to inform a larger model?

Tags: python, data-analysis

I have data in pairs - for instance, given subjects `A, B, C, D, E...` I might have data for the pairs `AB`, `AC`, `BD`, and `DE`. All data is relative to the other member of the pair, there is no absolute data. Each subject is paired directly with few other subjects, but all subjects are connected via some number of common links.

I would like to use these pairs to inform a model, such that I could reasonably extrapolate the value of `C` versus the value of `E` by using `C`'s relationship with `A`, `A`'s relationship with `B`, `B`'s relationship with `D`, and `D`'s relationship with `E`. Essentially, I would like to create a sort of web, where all data points affect and are affected by each other data point.

I'm struggling to figure out how to get started with such a model, on a high level - how to start weaving that web. So far I've programmed my data examination, cleaning, and transformation (to get the clean pairs of data) in Python using Pandas.

Answer (score -1):

object pairs. To improve the extraction performance, we introduce subject information at this stage. S=[w_{1},w_{2},\cdots , w_{n}] is the extracted subject sequence, and w_{i} is one of the tokens. Each token contained in S contributes differently to global information, so we generate the ensemble representation of the subject by the following formula:

\begin{aligned}{} & {} S_{\omega } ={\text {softmax}}(W_{2} \sigma (W_{1} S))\end{aligned}
(8)
\begin{aligned}{} & {} S_{en}=MeanPool(, \odot (S_{\omega }, , S) ,) \end{aligned}
(9)
where W_{e1} and W_{e2} are trainable parameters, \sigma is the activation function, and here is Relu, \odot denotes element-wise multiplication, MeanPool denotes mean pooling.

The problem of data overlap is abundant in relation–object pairs. To eliminate the interference of overlapping data, we perform the sequence-to-matrix transformation. The relation–object pair to be extracted has a relationship with the subject, so the information related to the subject should be included in the generated matrix. This section employs the Biaffine method to fuse subject features and generate the relation–sequence matrix. As shown in Fig. 3, the labels 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7 correspond to seven matrices M_{1}, M_{2}, M_{3}, M_{4}, M_{5}, M_{6}, and M_{7}, respectively. M_{1}=S_{en} is the subject representation generated earlier. M_{5}=S_{e} is the encoded sentence representation generated in Sect. NEDORT encoder”. Then we fuse the information of these two matrices and construct the relation–sequence matrix. To complete the transformation of sequence-to-matrix and introduce subject features, we extend M_{1} and generate the relation matrix M_{2}. There are numerous repeated expressions in the expanded matrix, so we design the matrix M_{3} to optimize it. M_{3} is generated by random initialization, and it can be dynamically adjusted during training. The matrix generated by the dynamically adjusted strategy is more conducive to the extraction of relational triples. M_{4}=M_{2}M_{3} is the matrix expression after optimization.Footnote4 The matrix to be generated is relation and sequence related. Therefore, we combine the relation-related matrix M_{4} and the sequence-related matrix M_{5} to generate the final relation–sequence matrix M_{7}. M_{7} can be generated by the formula M_{7}=M_{4}M_{6}, where M_{6}=(M_{5})^{T}. The whole process above can be expressed by

\begin{aligned} M_{bia} = Biaffine(S_{en}, S_{e}) \end{aligned}
(10)
where S_{en} is the subject representation, S_{en} is the sequence representation, M_{bia} is the generated matrix representation. The above formula completes the conversion of sequence to matrix and incorporates the subject features.

Fig. 4
figure 4
The structure of the U-Net network. Part 1 is the input matrix. The rest parts are convolution blocks with different number of channels. “cat” represents the information interaction between two blocks. The content in the lower right corner is the matrix dimension of the output

The extraction of relation–object pairs is more complicated than that of subjects. Although the design of M_{3} improves the inference capability of the model, it is difficult for the generated matrix to accurately extract the relation–object pairs corresponding to the subject. To optimize the matrix representation, we design the U-Net network. U-Net is a multi-layer convolutional neural network that can extract the deep features of the matrix. As shown in Fig. 2, the U-Net network consists of seven parts. Part 1 is the relation–sequence matrix obtained by the Biaffine method. Each of the remaining parts is composed of a two-layer convolutional neural network, and its formula is expressed as follows:

\begin{aligned} M_{out}= \sigma Conv(\sigma Conv(M_{in})) \end{aligned}
(11)
where Conv is the convolution operation and the convolution kernels of all parts are 3\times 3, \sigma is the activation function, and here is Relu, M_{in} is the input matrix, M_{out} is the output matrix, and the input and output of each part are different.

Figure 2 annotates the matrix dimension of the output for each step. Parts 2, 3, and 4 are down-sampling blocks whose output channels are constantly increasing. More channels can enlarge the receptive field of matrix embedding, thus providing rich global information between relations and sequences. Parts 5, 6, and 7 are up-sampling blocks, and their output channels are trending down. The reduction of the number of extracted features can make the model pay more attention to the token part corresponding to the object rather than the entire sequence. Moreover, there are information interactions between the down-sampling blocks and the up-sampling blocks. The combined matrix representation considers its contextual semantics while focusing on the object. Different from feature extraction in images, the obtained output matrix must have the same dimensions as the input matrix. Therefore, we design two Maxpooling layers and two Deconv layers in the down-sampling and up-sampling stages, respectively. The entire process can be expressed by:

\begin{aligned} M_{u} = UNet(M_{bia}) \end{aligned}
(12)
where M_{bia} is the relation–sequence matrix generated by the Biaffine method, M_{u} is the matrix representation after optimization.

Fig. 5
figure 5
Implementation details for the extraction of relational triples. “Head” and “Tail” represent predictions for start and end positions, respectively. Consecutive tokens marked in red are entities extracted from the sequence. “sub”, “Rel” and “obj” denote subject, relation and object, respectively

The optimized relation–sequence matrix has been obtained, and then we extract relation–object pairs on this basis. We complete the extraction of relation–object pairs by predicting the start and end positions of the object corresponding to each relation. The prediction formulas for these two positions are as follows:

\begin{aligned}{} & {} Ob^{s}=sigmoid(W_{o}^{s2}(W_{o}^{s1}\sigma ( M_{u})+b_{o}^{s1})+b_{o}^{s2})\end{aligned}
(13)
\begin{aligned}{} & {} Ob^{e}=sigmoid(W_{o}^{e2}(W_{o}^{e1}\sigma ( M_{u})+b_{o}^{e1})+b_{o}^{e2}) \end{aligned}
(14)
where W_{o}^{s1}, W_{o}^{s2}, W_{o}^{e1}, W_{o}^{e2}, b_{o}^{s1}, b_{o}^{s2}, b_{o}^{e1} and b_{o}^{e2} are trainable weights, \sigma is the activation function, and here is Relu. The object corresponding to a specific relation may be None, indicating that the relation–object pair containing this relation does not exist.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).